# Image overlay with padding and text centered

Tags: jquery, html, css

Need to add an overlay to an image that will have an all-around padding of say 10px and text "-- view details --" centered both vertically and horizontally. And I can't find anything on how to achieve this. Here is a [URL](http://grab.by/JZws) to the screenshot of what I need. And here is the [URL](http://grab.by/JZwC) of the original image when it's not in the :hover state.

Comment: sorry for not having any starting markup - but i have no idea where to start

Comment: Is it overlay on hover or static image + text?

Comment: it should appear on hover over - otherwise it should just show the image - no overlay and no text

Comment: my problem is adding the padding and also making the text centered and of course, keeping all that responsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.image {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: 25%;
}
.image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.details {
  display: none;
}
.image:hover .details {
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
.details span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://www.pixeldecor.com/patterns/color-samples/brikbrak-sample.gif" />
  <div class="details">
    <span>View details</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you - this is great! but is there any way to not make the image size fixed? As i need it responsive as I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and the image is 100% of it's container which resizes?

Comment: you nailed it - thanks! any browsers that won't support this?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.image {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://new.tinygrab.com/a8bc0638b9433ec64cb0bfc81091b1c77b45a66fe1.png") repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
}
.overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all ease 1s;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 300px;
  color: #747E8B;
  font-size: 2em;
  height: 0;
}
.image:hover .overlay {
  background: white;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">

  <div class="overlay">-- View Details --</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Is there any way of making this responsive as I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and the image is 100% of it's container which resizes?

Comment: Try using this code inside the Bootstrap grid. Otherwise the accepted solution looks good, you should try using that inside the bootstrap grid classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Here you go:**

```
.asdf{
    width:270px;
    height:150px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-75px 0 0 -135px;
    background-color:green;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:150px;
}
```

Heres a working fiddle [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/qhxrmdnw/)

Comment: Sorry, I have the image as a base and when I have the hoverOver on the image, then the gray box with the padding and the text needs to show.

Comment: just edited the original question to show the image without the :hover

Comment: The image-overlay should cover the whole image? or where should it appear?

Comment: here is the image in the original state - http://grab.by/JZwC. and here it is on :hover - http://grab.by/JZws